# Should I vote to close a question as duplicate when its duplicate has an outdated accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

I came across this question

[How to draw a transparent UIToolbar or UINavigationBar in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969248/how-to-draw-a-transparent-uitoolbar-or-uinavigationbar-in-ios7/18969325#18969325)

and I answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969325/846273.

Subsequently I found this topic: [Make UINavigationBar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/iphone-sdk-make-uinavigationbar-transparent/18969823#18969823), which is about the same issue, however the proposed solutions are outdated, so I just posted the same answer there.

Now, should I vote to close the first question as duplicate of the older one?

It's technically a duplicate, but the accepted answer is outdated, so I'm not sure whether it's a good idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

You should, if you can, also provide a more up-to-date answer to the original question.

You should not, unless it is now completely wrong, down-vote the outdated answer.

If you have already answered the duplicate then you should go back and delete that answer.

Comment: thank you. I just realized that the supposedly duplicated question is actually a little bit broader than the older one (it asks about `UIToolbar` too). I posted an update answer on the older one and I'll leave my first answer in place. Hope that's ok.

Comment: hmm I'd say answer the better question and then vote the worse question as the dupe of the better question. Or is it vote for dupe of the one with the better answers?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Unless you should.

The two things you should consider are 1. are these actually the same question and 2. do the answers of the previous question answer the current one?

If you aren't sure, then forget it.  Dupes aren't necessarily bad.  When the questions are exactly the same, and when knowledge is being spread out rather than centralized within the canonical one, is when you should consider voting to close as dupe.

You state that the "outdated" question doesn't answer the recent one.  In that case, voting to close as dupe doesn't make much sense.  If they are about different versions of whatever, perhaps it would be better to edit both questions to highlight this difference, so that people looking for version X know which question better fits their needs.

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > IMHO

Answer (score 1):

In addition to, or at least in lieu of, posting a more relevant answer, you should leave a comment on the outdated but accepted answer, along the lines of:

> While this answer is relevant for *version x.y*, if you are using *version y.z*, it is more relevant to... (or link to a newer, more relevant answer).

Unfortunately it's not possible to splice a question so that there is an accepted answer for *version x.y* and a different accepted answer for *version y.z*. We face this issue all the time in the *sql-server*-related tags, both on SO and on dba.SE. A question asked and answered before current versions existed may very well have a better answer today, but it can become quite tedious figuring out the best way to update the post to reflect this. I certainly agree with Chris that you shouldn't down-vote the accepted answer, because it was likely the best answer at the time, and probably is still the best answer for folks still stuck on whatever version that was.

Comment: This seems... not quite right. We can feasibly have a question asking about so-and-so problem in Visual Studio 2008, and then another question asking about the same problem in Visual Studio 2012 - and the latter won't be a duplicate if the VS2008 response doesn't work in VS2012. You **can** splice a question this way, by explicitly having one ask about one version, and another ask about it for a different version. In fact, when the solutions differ by version, it makes more sense to do _that_ than have one question cover multiple separate versions and expect answers to cover each of them.

Comment: @Jonathan it's not always that simple. Three years ago a question like "how do I calculate the median" would have one best answer. Today the same question would have a better answer but only if the user is using the latest version. Sadly too many people will still jump on the vote to close as a duplicate train. There also seems to be quite a bit of resistance to having a "how do I do this in 2000" question, another for 2005, another for 2008, 2012, etc.

Comment: @jonathan and what you're describing is not splicing a question, it's creating two separate questions. That was not what I was attempting to describe. I was talking about having a single canonical question, and having multiple version-specific best answers. Sometimes you will get an answer with various solutions for each version, but these often appear later (as new versions are released and best answers change) & long after an older answer has been accepted / received up-votes. All I'm saying is there isn't a simple, blanket way to deal with all of these situations the same way every time.